# How can I add/use two identical audio interfaces on a Mac?

Tags: mac, audio, ui, macos

I have two PreSonus Audiobox USB96 audio interfaces.  I would love to use both and create an aggregate device.  However, they both have the same name so Apple will only recognize whichever one I plug in second.  Is there any way to rename one (I know the names came from the devices themselves)?  This isn't an issue with two different models/brands/etc.

Apple Recognizes both under System Report (see below), but not in Audio MIDI Setup.  Any ideas would be helpful.

```
AudioBox USB 96:

  Product ID:   0x0303  
  Vendor ID:    0x194f  
  Version:  1.12  
  Serial Number:    000000000000  
  Speed:    Up to 480 Mb/s  
  Manufacturer: PreSonus  
  Location ID:  0x14300000 / **28**  
  Current Available (mA):   500  
  Current Required (mA):    500  
  Extra Operating Current (mA): 0  


AudioBox USB 96:

  Product ID:   0x0303  
  Vendor ID:    0x194f  
  Version:  1.12
  Serial Number:    000000000000  
  Speed:    Up to 480 Mb/s  
  Manufacturer: PreSonus  
  Location ID:  0x14100000 / **27**  
  Current Available (mA):   500  
  Current Required (mA):    500  
  Extra Operating Current (mA): 0
```